# Passing many ENVs to terraform template

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Is there a way to pass many ENVs altogether to template file in Terraform without declaring them each separately like this:

```
data "template_file" "test_template" {
  template = file("templates/container.tpl")
  vars = {
    ENV1 = var.ENV1
    ENV2 = var.ENV2
    ENV3 = var.ENV3
    ENV4 = var.ENV4
    ENV5 = var.ENV5
  }
}
```

And inside template having them like this?:

```
[
  {
    "essential": true,
    "memory": 300,
    "name": "client",
    "cpu": 300,
    "image": "some_image",
    "portMappings": [
        {
            "containerPort": 3000,
            "hostPort": 0
        }
    ],
    "environment": [
      { "name": "ENV1", "value": "${ENV1}" },
      { "name": "ENV2", "value": "${ENV2}" },
      { "name": "ENV3", "value": "${ENV3}" },
      { "name": "ENV4", "value": "${ENV4}" },
      { "name": "ENV5", "value": "${ENV5}" },
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: What version of Terraform are you using? And can you provide a more worked example of how this should work? Is the application expecting to retrieve the environment values at `ENV1` and `ENV2` etc? Or are you wanting to pass the key and value to the ECS task (eg `FOO = "BAR` => `{ "name": "FOO", "value": "BAR"}`.

Comment: My version is  0.12.26. Is the application expecting to retrieve the environment values at ENV1 and ENV2 etc - yes. Or are you wanting to pass the key and value to the ECS task -yes. All I want is not to declare them on template_file level and use some spread syntax (?) instead.

Answer (score 0):

In terraform 0.12, it is recommended you use:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/templatefile.html

Template:

```
%{ for addr in ip_addrs ~}
backend ${addr}:${port}
%{ endfor ~}
```

Call:

```
templatefile("${path.module}/backends.tmpl", { port = 8080, ip_addrs = ["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2"] })
```